# Should I use regex or just DOM/string manipulation?

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

Sometimes I am not sure when do I have to use one or another. I usually parse all sort of things with Python, but I would like to focus this question on HTML parsing.

Personally I find DOM manipulation really useful when having to parse more than two regular elements (i.e. title and body of a list of news, for example).

However, I found myself in situations where it is not clear for me to build a regex or try to get the desired value simply manipulating strings. A particular fictional example: I have to get the total number of photos of an album, and the only way to get this is parsing the number of photos using this way:

> (1 of 190)

So I have to get the '190' from the whole HTML document. I could write a regex for that, although regex for parsing HTML is not exactly the best, or that is what I always understood. On the other hand, using DOM seems overwhelming for me as it is just a simple element. String manipulation seems to be the best way, but I am not really sure if I should proceed like that in such a similar case.

Can you tell me how would you parse these kind of single elements from a HTML document using Python (or any other language)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a subjective question (with subjective answers) but in general I'd try to avoid using regex for parsing HTML/XML, as has been [previously discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201359) in SO. Only if the input string with the markup is small and with no possibilities of getting more complex, and the pattern being searched is unambiguous and easily described as a regex, would I use a regex. It's a matter of balancing the right tool for the job with the need to be practical.

For your concrete example, I think it'd be OK to start with a regex. But if you find yourself extracting additional information from the input and/or the regex starts to get cumbersome, switch to a parser.

Answer (score 2):

People shy away from doing regexes to search HTML because it isn't the right tool for the job when parsing tags. But everything should be considered on a case-by-case basis. You aren't searching for tags, you are searching for a well-defined string in a document. It seems to me the simplest solution is just a regex or some sort of XPath expression -- simple parsing requires simple tools.