# Regex match text between paragraph tags

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I'm attempting to match only the content between opening/closing paragraph tags. Playing around with it on RegExr, I can get `<p.*?>` to match an opening paragraph tag that may or may not have any additional attributes such as class and/or ID.

However, when I attempt to add that pattern to a positive look behind, it breaks and I'm not sure why. I've tried escaping the `<` and `>` symbols, but that doesn't seem to help. The look ahead, however, works perfectly.

Here's an example of the entire pattern:

`(?<=\<p.*?\>).*?(?=</p>)`

I'd like to be able to match only the content within the paragraph tags, and not include the tags themselves. Hence why I was attempting to use look aheads and look behinds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem with using lookbehinds is that in most regex engines, you are not allowed to use repetition inside of them.

```
(?<=.*)
```

This is invalid because of the `*` quantifier. If it was `{8}`, it would be okay since it is a fixed-width.

#### Solution

My advice is to match everything, and use capture groups and backreferences to process your data.

#### Example

```
<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p>
```

So, `$1` or `\1` would contain the data you want.

Comment: I wasn't aware that variable-width patterns weren't allowed in look-behinds. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with other tags like `<li>`? In a way that `<p>.*</li>` do not result in matches.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `regex` for this kind of task.There are many issues can be found.
see this post: [Should I use regex or just DOM/string manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048512/should-i-use-regex-or-just-dom-string-manipulation)

use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) it is very simple.

Sample example:

```
$str= "<p>tetsd</p> doutside <p> 232323234</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $para) {
    echo $para->textContent;
}
```

[live demo][1]
[1]:https://eval.in/107922

Comment: That's almost what I need. I can make the pattern match the tags and what's contained within them. The problem I'm having is that I don't want the paragraph tags to actually show up in the match results. That's why I was trying to use look ahead and look behinds...